# SQL Get leaderboard of top 50 most earned by table

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I don't really know how to do this in SQL, so that's why I'm here right now. So, I have a website where people can earn points, everything gets logged in a table called `earnings`. The table structure is `id (uniue), uid, username, amount`. I want to create a learerboard of "most earned points", where I want to get the total earned points and the username. How can I do this in SQL?

Example:
Table:

```
id | uid | username | amount
------------------------------
1  | 1   | user1    | 5
2  | 1   | user1    | 1
3  | 2   | user2    | 3
4  | 1   | user1    | 4
5  | 2   | user2    | 10
```

When using the SQL, it should give as result:

```
user2 | 13
user1 | 10
```

But then this with a table with 1500 rows, getting the top 50. I don't even know if this is possible, I hope it is.

Thanks for reading/helping!

Comment: Uhh I dont think that I get the joke @LaurentLequenne

Comment: Did you try `group by` and `sum`?

Comment: Just search google on "select n potatoes from an ordered bag" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the query below, you can get the top 50 username who are all having the highest sum value:

```
SELECT username, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM earnings
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try using limit 50  and group by for aggregated  result

```
select username, sum(amount) 
from my_table 
group by username
order by sum(amount) DESC 
limit 50
```